# Can't access global variable in PHP codeigniter Model class.

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope, public

I have a class in Codeigniter which extends CI_Model.

I have declared a global array **$data**, but I can't access this array from my functions which i want to push some items.
that shows

**A PHP Error was encountered Message: Undefined variable: data**

and **Fatal error:** Cannot access empty property in **/api/system/core/Model.php** on line 51

**code for class:**

```
class Subscription_collection_model extends CI_Model {
        public $data=array();
    /*
    |-----------------------------------------
    | Constructor
    |-----------------------------------------
    */

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
            }

    function get() {

            $this->db->select('family.house_name,family.id,family_grade.amount');
            $this->db->from('family');
            $this->db->join('family_grade','family_grade.id = family.family_grade_id');
            $query = $this->db->get();
             if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
               {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                    {
                        $this->findBalance($row->id);
                     }
                }    
         return $data;
        }


     function findBalance($id) {

        $this->db->where('family_id', $id);
        $this->db->select_sum('collecting_amount');
        $query = $this->db->get('subscription_collection');

           if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
               {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                    {
                        array_push($this->$data,$row->collecting_amount);


                     }
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return $data;` should be `return $this->data` perhaps? Also not `array_push($this->$data` but `array_push($this->data`

Comment: k.thanks but when i  push $query to $data it shows error. how to push each row of $query result and push an item in each row from findBalance() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got a typo there. you want to call `$this->data` not `$this->$data`.
the latter would assume, you wanna call a dynamic variable on the instance.

```
$prop = 'myProperty';
$this->$prop = 'test';
```

is the same as

```
$this->myProperty = 'test';
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
return $this->data;
```